# Apple Magic mouse/ Apple Magic Trackpad /Bring up all windows gesture

Tags: 11.04

Hello everyone my question is. Is it possible for the magic mouse to have different gesture other than the scroll wheel gesture. I wanted to do the bring up all windows gesture or the super + W gesture. Do you guys know if the mouse is going to have better support in ubuntu 11.10? Is there any software that can enable me to do different gestures with the mouse just like how it works in os x ?

Trackpad question
I been trying to configure magic trackpad also with touchegg, but touchegg is not working for me. What do I do help me out guys!!! I don't if I did the installation wrong or what. I'm running ubuntu 11.04.

How do I disable the unity gestures to allow touchegg to run.

- I think I found the answer to my problem. I think I'm using the wrong gui with the wrong version. Currently I have vr.1 and running the 0.3 gui, which is not working at all. I check the touchegg forums and it seem like jose the guy that created the program is working on the vr.1 GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me in Ubuntu 11.10:

You should be able to do a 4-finger tap to bring up the Dash, and do a four-finger swipe to hide & unhide the Launcher.

A three finger drag on a non-maximised window moves the window around, and brings up resize handles.

As far as I'm aware this is the current set of gestures supported by Unity.  Unity *also* claims all four-finger gestures (and I think it also claims three-finger gestures), so while Unity is running no other app will be able to provide those gestures.

Comment: Yeah that works like a charm, but I'm trying to run touchegg and I'm in the gui interface,but nothing works. Also @RAOF if you are using a trackpad how did you configure it with touchegg. Thanks for the help. Maybe I install touchegg wrong or something I don't know. I installed the deb file, but I install an older version of the gui interface. I don't know if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 11.10 also support three finger pinch to maximize/restore the window.